# Mod remainders of Biprimes and their factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I would postulate the following:

Let $B$ be a biprime with two different odd factors $p$ and $q$

Then at least one integer n exists such that

$p\equiv x \pmod n$ and $q\equiv y \pmod n$ and $B \equiv (x*y) \pmod n$, holds true

where: 
$x$ and $y$ are either 1 or odd primes; $x*y <n$; $n <p$ and $n<q$; $n \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ and 
$n>2$.

My experimental research found at least one n for all of the biprimes between 1e11 and 1.001e11 where p/q<2. There were 21580 such biprimes, and 4 of these had only one n result. I searched between n=4 and n=B^0.5.

Can anyone provide any theoretical basis for the postulate?

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Why not take $x=p,y=q$?

Comment: @lulu some details were not showing up because of use of `<` outside math mode - I've edited so all the information is there now.

Comment: Thank you Especially Lime!

Comment: It's still confusing.  $p\equiv x \pmod n, q\equiv y \pmod n\implies B=pq\equiv xy\pmod n$ so that condition is redundant.  And there are infinitely many primes congruent to $p$ or $q$ $\pmod n$ so long as $n$ is prime to both.

Comment: Perhaps a detailed, non-trivial, numerical example would clarify your meaning.

Comment: Ah, I see that you require $xy<n$ so I can't take $(x,y)=(p,q)$, nor will Dirichlet help me.  But still.  If we take $n=8$ then $p,q$ are each congruent to one of $\{1,3,5,7\}$ $\pmod 8$ and, as it happens, any of those will work for you.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime  Thanks!

Comment: The biprime 100000194313 only provides one solution, and that is for n=14 where:

biprime factor 291887 is 5 (mod 14) 
biprime factor 342599 is 1 (mod 14)
biprime 100000194313 is 5 (mod 14)
...

We need to go up to n = almost B^0.5 to ensure complete coverage. The smallest of the 2 solutions for biprime 100008836173 is 

biprime factor 309599 is 23 (mod 309576), 
biprime factor 323027 is 13451 (mod 309576)
biprime 100008836173 is 309373 (mod 309576)..

At the other end of the scale: biprime 100008007241 provides 176 solutions, of which 158 comprise x and y both prime.

Comment: @lulu. Your example with n=8, the only solutions are where x*y<8, i.e. x=1 with y 1,3,5,7. If x=3,5,7 then y must be 1. This rules out any solutions where x and y are both 3 or more.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification.  Interesting (+1).  Looks hard to prove.

Comment: It has been pointed out to me that p and q must both be odd primes >3. This is because the minimum value of n = 4

Comment: Somebody has shown that biprime 649 is the first example for which there are no solutions. There are over 5e5 exceptions under 1e9 many with one small biprime factor. The conjecture then does not stand. It has been an interesting excursion.

Comment: I am looking at a wider conjecture that requires n to be less than the larger of p and q. This has no small exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above in comments, in order to have any valid $n$ we need $p,q>3$.

$n=4$ will always be a solution if either $p\equiv 1$ or $q\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ (although when $p\equiv q\equiv 3 \bmod 4$, $n=8$ is not a solution either). Similarly for $p,q>5$, $n=6$ will always be a solution if either $p\equiv 1$ or $q\equiv 1 \bmod 6$. So any counterexample will have $p,q\equiv 11 \bmod 12$.

You state in comments that $649 = 11\cdot 59$ is a counterexample, so let's look at that. Note that there are only four possible values for $n \in \{4,6,8,10\}$ and that we already know that $4,6$ and $8$ are not going to work. Then $(p,q)\equiv (1,9)\bmod 10$, which only fails due to the requirement for $y$ to be prime.

Without the prime requirement, of course you can always take $n=p{-}1$ (with $p<q$).

Comment: Thank you Joffan, very helpful.